# Magento Community - /customer/account/login/form not showing.

Tags: php, xml, magento

I deleted the customer registration form from the xml file for this page https://zabezi.com/customer/account/login/

I was attempting to identify the correct XML file to fix some other issues. I removed and replaced the section below, flushed Magento's cache and cleared my browser's cache but I can't get the form to display.

This is what I removed and replaced:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><liParams/><aParams>class="top-link-account"</aParams></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I found out what the problem was. I when I replaced the code, I did not place it where I removed it from.

Answer (score 0):

hello there are issue is <`liParams/>`

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><aParams>class="top-link-account"</aParams></action>
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain your answer?

Comment: if you not any element for li,then  it not need